# When reflecting: Should set property or directly set value? (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, reflection, properties, xml-serialization

I'm writing an xml serialization class for objective-c.
The point is to give the class a class type and an xml file.
It should return an instance with data.

I've got it working, and it does quite a bit - handles primitives (+nsstring), user defined classes and nsarrays. Doesn't handle pointers or C-arrays.
Obviously this relies heavily on reflection.

The question: When I set a value of an instance of some class, should I be checking if a property with the right name exists, or can I just set the variable using simple reflection?

This is the kind of code I've used so far:

```
id newClass = class_createInstance(NSClassFromString(elementName), sizeof(unsigned));
Ivar nameVar = class_getInstanceVariable([newClass class], "name");
if (nameVar != nil)
    object_setIvar(newClass, nameVar, [NSString stringWithString:@"George"]);
```

Also, after this kind of assignment, should I release anything?

Comment: Why aren't you using NSKeyedArchiver for this? or CoreData?

Answer (score 6):

Uh... you usually *don't* need to get so low into the runtime to do what that code does.  The following is fully functional and does exactly the same thing:

```
id newObject = [[NSClassFromString(elementName) alloc] init];
@try {
  [newObject setValue:@"George" forKey:@"name"];
@catch (NSException *e) {
  if ([[e name] isEqualToString:NSUndefinedKeyException]) {
    NSLog(@"%@ does not recognize the property \"name\"", elementName);
  }
}

//... do stuff with newObject
[newObject release];
```

If you need to put in other things, like floats or ints or structs, you can box them into an NSValue (or subclass), and then pass those to `setValue:forKey:`.  For example:

```
NSNumber * aFloat = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:42.0];
[newObject setValue:aFloat forKey:@"aFloatIvar"];

NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 42, 54);
NSValue * aStruct = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&frame objcType:@encode(NSRect)];
[newObject setValue:aStruct forKey:@"aStructIvar"];
```

Comment: The problem with this code is that it doesn't work for primitive types. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Put your primitives into an NSValue object (like NSValue or NSNumber) and the internals will automatically unbox them.

Comment: NSValue wants "objCType:(const char *)type".
How do I get the type? (Assuming without class_getInstanceVariable)

Comment: The code assumes prior knowledge of the type (float, NSRect).
Is there an easy way to get the primitive type of a variable of a class so I can switch on it to do the above?

Comment: @Dror I don't know. What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: @DaveDeLong - This is promising for me and may be my answer **if I fully understood it right now**  I am absorbing the information here.  But if you are so inclined to give me another answer for more points, please see my question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/25538890/1735836