# Set property values of an Objective-C class using reflection

Tags: objective-c, reflection

I am trying to learn reflection in Objective-C.  I've found some great information on how to dump the property list of a class, especially [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2302808/1735836), but I want to know if it is possible to set a property's value using reflection.

I have a dictionary of keys (property names) and values (all `NSString`s).  I want to use **Reflection** to get the property and then set its value to the value in my dictionary.  Is this possible?  Or am I dreaming?

This has nothing to do with the dictionary.  I am merely using the dictionary to send in the values.

Like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/619767/1735836), but for Objective C.

```
- (void)populateProperty:(NSString *)value
{
    Class clazz = [self class];
    u_int count;

    objc_property_t* properties = class_copyPropertyList(clazz, &count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++)
    {
        const char* propertyName = property_getName(properties[i]);
        NSString *prop = [NSString  stringWithCString:propertyName encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        // Here I have found my prop
        // How do I populate it with value passed in?
    }
    free(properties);

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Objective C properties automatically conform to the `NSKeyValueCoding` protocol. You can use `setValue:forKey:` to set any property value by a string property name.

```
NSDictionary * objectProperties = @{@"propertyName" : @"A value for property name",
                                    @"anotherPropertyName" : @"MOAR VALUE"};

//Assuming class has properties propertyName and anotherPropertyName
NSObject * object = [[NSObject alloc] init];

for (NSString * propertyName in objectProperties.allKeys)
{
    NSString * propertyValue = [objectProperties valueForKey:propertyName];

    [object setValue:propertyValue
              forKey:propertyName];
}
```

Comment: It is reflection. The property mutator and accessor is called when you use this method.

Comment: @Lucy [`setValue:forKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000471-BABEHECF) is part of the `NSKeyValueCoding` protocol, which `NSObject` conforms to. It has nothing to do with dictionaries; you're thinking of `setObject:forKey:`, which is a method on `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: @Lucy `setValue:forKey:` jumps through a bunch of hoops, finds the setter, and calls it.  It is reflection.   And it is generally to be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

The `NSKeyValueCoding` protocol, which `NSObject` implements (see NSKeyValueCoding.h), contains the method [`-setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000471-BABBIHEB). This method takes exactly the kind of dictionary you describe and sets the appropriate properties (or ivars) of the reciever.

This is absolutely reflection; the code in `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:` accesses the properties by the names you give it, and will even find the appropriate ivar if no setter method exists.

Comment: This is reflection; just because you didn't write the reflective code doesn't mean that's not what it is.